# Mining a Dataframe for a Count of Unique Words

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-mining, text-parsing

I'm looking to take a set of strings in a dataframe and then break those strings up in order to get a count of distinct words in the strings. The ultimate idea is this:

Word 1: 5 times

Word 2: 3 times

Word 3: 10 times

...

Word n: 13 times

The ultimate goal is to take this set of strings, then extend the analysis into groupings of 2 words, 3 words, and so on.

I've tried multiple packages, including Pandas, re, collections and so on, but nothing seems to get me where I need.

```py
import pandas as pd

import re


fPath = 'path\there'
fName = '\BuzzWords.xlsx'

importExcel = pd.read_excel(fPath+fName, sheetname = 'DATA')
importExcel.sort_index(inplace = True)

bWList = ['words','things']

pattern = '(?i)('+'|'.join(bWList)+')'

minerFrame = importExcel[0:0]

dFCounter = max(importExcel.index)

for i in range(0,dFCounter+1):

    temp = importExcel[i:i+1]

    checker = temp[temp['description'].str.contains(pattern)]

    checker2 = checker.isnull().sum().sum()

    if checker2 > 0:
        minerFrame = minerFrame.append(temp)

minerFrame = minerFrame.reset_index(drop = True)
```

That code should, ultimately lead to this kind of result:

Word 1: 10

Word 2: 20

Word 3: 14

...

2-Word-Combo: 10

2-Word-Combo: 15

...

3-Word-Combo: 30

3-Word-Combo: 40

...

etc.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: perhaps look into Counter and itertools.combinations

Comment: Thank you very much! I checked out the Counter package and this code worked perfectly:

```Counter(" ".join(minerFrame.description).split(" ")).items()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris mentioned, the `Counter` object from `collections` library will return a dictionary of unique words, with a count of them.  So you could do something like:

```
from collections import Counter

#...
bwDict = {}
for word in bwList:
    bwDict[word] = 0

for i in range(0,dFCounter+1):

    content = importExcel.loc[i, 'description']
    for key, val in Counter(content).items():
        if key in bwDict.keys():
            bwDict[key] += val
```

This won't return the combinations count, but your existing code using re library should return that.